# Convert UTC time in Local using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetime, time, timezone, data-conversion

I am this time format `(2-12-2015 02:06)` and want to convert it according to country local time.
For this I am using this Angular Code

```
{{cat.Created_Timestamp | date:'d-M-y HH:mm' : 'UTC'}}
```

But it is not displaying time according to local time.

Answer (score 0):

try this   `{{date | date:'dd MMM yyyy' | lowercase }}`